How to make express server to catch JWT expiry error without stopin the server?
I have an angular app running on some port and an express server running on another port.
Both running locally on my laptop.
I'm testing my api by sending requests from angular to express and I'm having issues with catching errors when JWT token is expired.
exports.someFunction = async (req, res, next) => {
  if(!jwt.verify(payload, SECRET)) {
    return res.status(400).json('someError');
  }
  
  jwt.verify(payload, SECRET, async function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json('someError');
    }
    else {
      return res.status(200).json('someResponse');
    }
 })
}

Now instead of sending an error to my angular app, like it does for instance in case of failed db query with the same error code, it immediately breaks the express listening process with expiry error:

TokenExpiredError: jwt expired

I need to be able to catch that error now so I know it won't be a problem after it's deployed on a production server.

Offhand, this code looks ok. Can you share a [mcve] that demonstrates the crash?

You try to verify it twice, in two different ways (once assuming it's synchronous, once async). Also passing an async error-first callback in which you don't await anything doesn't seem right.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "minimal". That IS the function I'm using in its entirety. All I  changed was names to "someError" etc

@jonrsharpe yes, one is for token that is wrong (missing a part or different) and second check is for it being actually expired

@jonrsharpe I can add "await" signature to that first error response but it won't change the fact express stops listening after jwt expired error has been registered. And also the error in the first check is different and its: JsonWebTokenError: invalid token which also breaks express and it stops listening

I found correct way of catching error for express not to break listening:
jwt.verify(token, SECRET, async function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Token expired' });
      }
      if(err.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Token invalid' });
      }
    }
    else {
      return res.status(200).json('Token verified');
    }
 })


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
